# Why doesn't the destructor get called?

Tags: c++

I am using RAII and using `try`/`catch` to not leak memory for example. Here is an implementation in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void g(){
    throw 5;
}

class Rand{
public:
    ~Rand(){
        cout << "Randomm Destructor called" << endl;
    }
    int a = 17;
};

void f(){
    auto p = std::make_unique<Rand>(); //Should call dtor
    Rand* r = new Rand(); //Shouldnt call dtor
    cout << p->a << endl; //Prints 17
    g();
    cout << "This never executes" << endl;
}


int main(){
    f();
}
```

Due to stackunwinding and using RAII with the `std::unique_ptr`, shouldn't the destructors *for stack allocated objects* be called as a basic guarantee to `throw`/`try` since an exception is being thrown?

Comment: Since there's no catch block, unwinding may not be performed. Try catching g's exception in main.

Comment: @NicholasWilson, so if no unwinding happens, then what happens? Shouldn't it automatically unwind to *try to find a catch block?*

Comment: After application finishing execution due to exception OS would free memory, but destructor won't be executed. Isn't it so?

Comment: Indeed, it does try to find a catch block - but you haven't provided one. Unwinding (may) begin by searching for the catch block (you haven't given your OS/arch/libc, and platforms can implement this differently).

Answer (score 4):

From [throw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> Stack unwinding
>
> As the control flow moves up the call stack, destructors are invoked
>   for all objects with automatic storage duration constructed, but not
>   yet destroyed, **since the corresponding try-block was entered**, in
>   reverse order of completion of their constructors.

There is no corresponding try-block in your code, so no destructors are called and the program is terminated.

If you change the program as:

```
try
{
    auto p = std::make_unique<Rand>(); //Should call dtor
    Rand* r = new Rand(); //Shouldnt call dtor
    cout << p->a << endl; //Prints 17
    g();
    cout << "This never executes" << endl;
}
catch (int) {}
```

you will see, that the destructor for the object which is wrapped into `unique_ptr` is called.